# how does someone Align several images on the web page vertically(one on top of the other) using css?

Tags: html, css

How is it possible to align several images in a vertical order one below the other on the left hand side of the screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block` on all of them and they will behave like DIVs and align like you want them to by default.

A simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
    img.block{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<img class="block" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Google logo" />
<img class="block" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Google logo" />
<img class="block" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Google logo" />
<img class="block" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Google logo" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example? Do you have a URL we can look at? I mean, this can easily be done, it all depends in what context you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS should do it

```
display: block; float: left; clear: both;
```

Comment: What it the point of `float: left; clear: both;`? Why enforce a default behavior? What you wrote is a CSS pleonasm.

Answer (score -1):

This would be the easiest and quickest. (not the best method)

```
<h4>This table has no borders:</h4>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>image.gif</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>image.gif</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>image.gif</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>image.gif</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: DEFINITELY not the best!  BTW the -1 was not from me.

Comment: It was Alin that gave the -1, wasn't it! Your going down Alin!